# Does Oracle Coherence support bulk delete operations?

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-coherence

Right now I am sending 10,000 delete operations to a Coherence server sequentially. As a result, there are 10,000 network round trips. Is there a way to send all delete operations in 1 bulk operation to Coherence to avoid this round trip?

I've researched the documentation and found that there's a way to execute commands in batch but only when running the coherence.sh (via bin/coherence.sh "@batch batchfile.txt"), but not sure how to do this through their C# API and/or cache-config files.

Does anyone have an example on how to do this through C# (not java)?

Comment: Did you try solutions with [ConditionalRemove](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E15727_01/html/919a417f-0ed2-254e-f842-dd9d416946e3.htm) class?

Comment: Do you need help with Java or C#?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [`AbstractCacheStore.eraseAll(Collection colKeys)`](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/coherence/330/com/tangosol/net/cache/AbstractCacheStore.html#eraseAll(java.util.Collection))

[From the documentation:](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHDG/gs_intro.htm#COHDG5152)

> If you want to implement read/write caching, you must extend `com.tangosol.net.cache.AbstractCacheStore` (or implement the interface `com.tangosol.net.cache.CacheStore`), which adds the following methods:
>
> ```
> public void erase(Object oKey);
> public void eraseAll(Collection colKeys);
> public void store(Object oKey, Object oValue);
> public void storeAll(Map mapEntries);
> ```
>
> The method `erase()` should remove the specified key from the external data source. The method `store()` should update the specified item in the data source if it exists, or insert it if it does not presently exist.
>
> After the `CacheLoader`/`CacheStore` is implemented, it can be connected through the coherence-`cache-config.xml` file.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov He edited the post, the initial post said Java.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHNR/toc.htm) documentation, this is the proper **C# interface** for what you need:

> **AbstractCacheStore.EraseAll Method:**
>
> Remove the specified keys from the underlying store if present.
>
> **Namespace**:
>
> Tangosol.Net.Cache Assembly: Coherence (in Coherence.dll)
>   Version: 12.1.2.0 (12.1.2.0) Collapse imageSyntax
>
> **public void EraseAll(ICollection keys)**
>
> The implementation of this method calls **Erase(Object) for each key in
>   the supplied ICollection.** Once erased successfully, a key is removed
>   from the ICollection (if possible). Note: For many types of persistent
>   stores, a single erase operation is as expensive as a bulk erase
>   operation; therefore, subclasses should override this method if
>   possible.

It looks that even the underlying API that erases the whole collection does so by calling `Erase` on each value. Though, Oracle Coherence is an *in-memory cache*, so it isn't actually going *over the wire* 10,000 times to erase the keys, its accessing it in memory.

Comment: How do I wire this into my cache-config.xml file though?

Comment: Can you add your cache-config to the question?

Comment: @HenleyChiu See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHCG/net_library.htm#COHCG5082) documentation.

Comment: @HenleyChiu Did you manage to look at the docs? Do you have any further questions?

Comment: No, never mind, this is not really a solution, just marked as such as SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
cache.InvokeAll(filter, new ConditionalRemove(AlwaysFilter.INSTANCE));
```

or

```
cache.InvokeAll(colKeys, new ConditionalRemove(AlwaysFilter.INSTANCE));
```

Comment: This code is for Java. But I can attest that it works.